# Show that$f$ is in $R [0,1] $ (Riemann Integrable) and find find $\int_{0}^{1} $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

Show that $f$ is in $\mathscr R[0,1]$ (Riemann integrable) and find$\int_{0}^{1} f$

$f(x)=$
 \begin{cases} 
      1 &  0 < x<1 \\
       \\
      0 & x=1  ,x=0 
   \end{cases}

So I am having trouble with $U(P,f)$ and $L(P,f)$. Please help me as i need to study this.

would $P=[1,1-1/n,1]$ and would $\triangle x_i =1/n$

Comment: You want for all $\epsilon > 0$, you have $U(P,f) - L(P,f) < \epsilon$ for some partition $P$. If you calculate $U(P,f)$ (Upper Darboux sum), you should get $1$. It is left for you to pick a partition so that $L(P,f)$ has the above property. I'm not familiar with your usage the partition notation, but using equally space apart subinterval with your given $\Delta x$ will work for $n$ sufficiently large enough.

Comment: @MathNewbie ok i did get that U(P,f)=1. So L(P,f) should be 1 as well right?

Comment: You can't get $L(P,f)$ to be $1$ but it can be close to $1$ on your choice of $P$.

Answer (score 0):

Fix $\epsilon > 0$. By the Archimedian property, you can choose $N \in \mathbb{N}$, so for $n > N$

\begin{align*} \frac{1}{n} < \frac{\epsilon}{2} \end{align*}

Then choose a partition $P = \{x_0=0, x_1= \frac{1}{n}, \dots, x_{n-1}= \frac{n-1}{n}, x_n=1\}$ and observe that

$\inf\{f([x_{i-1},x_i])\} = \begin{cases} 0 \quad \text{if } i=1 \ \mathrm{or \ } i=n  \\ 1 \quad\text{otherwise} \end{cases}$

If you compute $L(P,f)$, you should have it equals $1-\frac{2}{n}$. Hence,

$U(P,f) - L(P,f) = 1 - (1-\frac{2}{n}) = \frac{2}{n} < \epsilon$

Comment: You could just choose $P = \{0,1/n,1-1/n,1\}.$

Comment: Yeah, forgot. That's even easier.

Comment: @zwh thanks! i kept going back and forth of choosing P={0,1/n,1} or P={0,1-1/n,1}